# Wiring stapled across bottom of beams? Can a running board be attached and the wires secured to the running board?

Tags: electrical, wiring

What's the best way to have these wires to code? Can a running board be used like in the picture?
[image: diagram]

Thanks,
[image: existing wiring on bottom of beams]
John

Answer (score 3):

1/2” plywood is legal and would work great in this case pop all the anchors slip the wood in place and everything will be to code  NEC exhibit 334.1 has a great example of exactly this.
Your example is a good one but I tend to go directly to the code book as it is the document most jurisdictions use in the US and that is my location.

Comment: Not sure what happened when I hit edit a duplicate was created so I deleted the short one.

Comment: Just to confirm, the way these wires are run is explicitly _not_ to code?

Comment: It depends on the date installed but seeing colored sheaths anything smaller than #6/8 requires a “rat run” or running board to protect the wires from damage. If no board the wires can be damaged by pushing up or pulling down then the staples break the sheath. With the board movement is limited. I am not sure of the beginning date but but it has been code for a long time. Bored holes do not require  it and parallel as long as 1-1/4 back are ok also. This is for exposed work like a crawl space or ceiling

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've got some _old_ fabric coated wiring in my crawl space that runs from joist-to-joist, so, in my youthful exuberance, I copied that when I installed newer NM-B/Romex 25+ years ago. Guess I should probably cut some plywood and fix things up nicely.

Comment: Can the the orange 8awg and black 6agw be on the 1/2 plywood? Do the wires need to be spaced out a specific distance on the plywood. I'm thinking about cutting a 2 foot wide 1/2 inch piece of plywood and attach to the beam and then attach all the wires.

Comment: They (the larger cables ) can be on the board also and they can be tightly spaced just enough room for the staples I believe a #6 can have 2 conductors and #8 have 3 without a board but it’s even better to have the board for them also and it looks neater in my opinion. If you have the space.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I'll put them all on a board.

Comment: John if this is helpful thanks are from up voting and the check mark if you accept the answer. This also helps others to find an accepted answer.

Comment: I posted another question about my dryer line. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/213838/is-it-ok-that-the-cable-for-my-dryer-circuit-is-suspended-from-the-ceiling  The comments said it needs to be in conduit since it's not in a framed wall and is exposed and it's below 8 feet. My basement isn't 8 feet high so do all of the wire that I'm going to staple to my running board need to be in conduit? Thanks, John

Comment: Ceiling it the ceiling if it is a crawl space or 7’ ceiling electrical code doesn't specify the height in this case and yes I have seen 7’ and shorter run exposed.

Comment: Thanks Ed. My ceiling is 6'8". I could put the wires in conduit but I'd rather not.