# Is it ok that the cable for my dryer circuit is suspended from the ceiling?

Tags: dryer, wire, conduit

I have a dryer line hanging from the ceiling joist. Will it pass code if it's attached to the poured concrete basement wall? Do I need to put the wire through conduit? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Looks like it might also be a NEMA 10 rather than a NEMA 14

Comment: BTW - that black line on the right of the picture _looks_ like another electrical cable. If it is, it needs to be secured to the wall and protected as well. Make one chase (2 @ 2x4, on either side of the wires) to cover them both.

Comment: @FreeMan  Good catch.  I thought it was a gas pipe...which probably also should have been secured, idk. But looking closely at it it might be a cable. Boxing in both together is a great suggestion: Install the dryer outlet box in the chase  and you're done!  Good idea.      +

Comment: That black line is coming from an air compressor. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not.

It needs to be protected in conduit or a covered stud wall at least 8' up as measured from the floor. And, like others have said, it needs to be secured.

Comment: Does the wall really need to be covered? Unfinished basements have wiring in them as far as the eye can see around here.

Comment: @isherwood  I believe technically it does. Imagine cable going thru drilled studs at about 4' (typical height) in an open wall.  People could hang tools, equipment, cleaning equipment, etc on those cables.  It would be stupid, but people do stupid stuff. Not sure if it needed when stapled to a stud vertically, but I think so.  Again, if it's in joists along the ceiling and it's over 8' protection isn't needed.

Comment: @isherwood The cable needs to have some sort of damage shield up to a certain height, that's a statutory requirement to keep it from getting struck by something.  Most people just use a stick of EMT conduit coming out of a J-box up to the required height, then the cable just exits the conduit stick.

Comment: I have the wire running across the ceiling beams on a running board but the ceiling in my basement isn't 8 feet high. Does the wire have to be in conduit on the running board?

Comment: Technically, probably yes. Where does the cable come from? Does it come from a panel on the main floor and pop out thru a bottom plate? Or?  What you have now sounds pretty safe, except for the dangling outlet.  But if and when you go to sell your home, it will get called out by a home inspector. Conduit is cheap, you can run your existing cable inside conduit, just make sure you get a large enough size to easily pull it. Cable is harder to pull than individual wires so go it bit larger than required.

Comment: The panel is in the basement and there are multiple wires on the running board. I guess I'll have to put them all in conduit. Thanks, John

Comment: @john  Probably you don't have to run everything in conduit.  Given that new information, it might be OK to just box in the running board. Like isherwood said, there are lots of unfinished basements where he is that have exposed wiring. Does the fact that it's "unfinished" make a difference?   Probably time to check with your local inspectors or electricians to see what's acceptable in your area.

Comment: Thanks George. I try and track down an inspector.